# XmlSerializer c++ Deserialize with multiple namespaces

Tags: c++, xml, namespaces, deserialization, xmlserializer

I am having the following problem, concerning the XmlSerializer of Microsoft (c++) and the deserialization process.  The ds:signature is not desiarialized and I get Undentified value. Can someone spot any mistake? My code is as follows:
My xml is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<test  xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
    <aa>
        <version>0.1.1</version>
    </aa>
    <bb>
        <cc>
            <Id>134324321421</Id>
            <ds:Signature>
                <ds:SignedInfo>
                    <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315#WithComments"/>
                    <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"/>
                    <ds:Reference Id="1" Type="" URI="something">
                        <ds:Transforms>
                            <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>
                        </ds:Transforms>
                        <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
                        <ds:DigestValue>43=</ds:DigestValue>
                    </ds:Reference>
                </ds:SignedInfo>
                <ds:SignatureValue>
                4344
            </ds:SignatureValue>
                <ds:KeyInfo>
                    <ds:KeyValue>
                        <ds:RSAKeyValue>
                            <ds:Modulus>
                            4543434
                        </ds:Modulus>
                            <ds:Exponent>43</ds:Exponent>
                        </ds:RSAKeyValue>
                    </ds:KeyValue>
                    <ds:X509Data>
                        <ds:X509Certificate>
                        3454343243242
                    </ds:X509Certificate>
                    </ds:X509Data>
                </ds:KeyInfo>
            </ds:Signature>
        </cc>
    </bb>
</aa>
```

And my code is as follows:

```
#using <mscorlib.dll>
#using <System.dll>
#using <System.Xml.dll>

// 
// This source code was auto-generated by xsd, Version=2.0.50727.3038.
// 
using namespace System::Xml::Serialization;
using namespace System;
namespace ds{

ref class _KeyInfo;
ref class _KeyValue;
ref class _RSAKeyValue;
ref class _X509Data;
ref class _Reference;
ref class _Transforms;
ref class _Transform;
ref class _DigestMethod;
ref class _Signature;
ref class _SignedInfo;
ref class _CanonicalizationMethod;
ref class _SignatureMethod;


/// <remarks/>

public ref class _KeyInfo {

    private: _KeyValue^  keyValueField;

    private: _X509Data^  x509DataField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public: [System::Xml::Serialization::XmlElement("KeyValue", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig")]
    property _KeyValue^  KeyValue {
        _KeyValue^  get();
        System::Void set(_KeyValue^  value);
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public: [System::Xml::Serialization::XmlElement("X509Data", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig")]
    property _X509Data^  X509Data {
        _X509Data^  get();
        System::Void set(_X509Data^  value);
    }
};


public ref class _KeyValue {

    private: _RSAKeyValue^  rSAKeyValueField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public: [System::Xml::Serialization::XmlElement("RSAKeyValue", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig")]
    property _RSAKeyValue^  RSAKeyValue {
        _RSAKeyValue^  get();
        System::Void set(_RSAKeyValue^  value);
    }
};


public ref class _RSAKeyValue {

    private: System::String^  modulusField;

    private: System::String^ exponentField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public: [System::Xml::Serialization::XmlElement("Modulus", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig")]
    property System::String^  Modulus {
        System::String^  get();
        System::Void set(System::String^  value);
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public: [System::Xml::Serialization::XmlElement("Exponent", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig")]
    property System::String^ Exponent {
        System::String^ get();
        System::Void set(System::String^ value);
    }
};


public ref class _X509Data {

    private: System::String^  x509CertificateField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public: [System::Xml::Serialization::XmlElement("X509Certificate", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig")]
    property System::String^  X509Certificate {
        System::String^  get();
        System::Void set(System::String^  value);
    }
};


public ref class _Reference {

    private: _Transforms^  transformsField;

    private: _DigestMethod^  digestMethodField;

    private: System::String^ digestValueField;

    private: System::String^ idField;

    private: System::String^ typeField;

    private: System::String^ uRIField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public: [System::Xml::Serialization::XmlElement("Transforms", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig")]
    property _Transforms^  Transforms {
        _Transforms^  get();
        System::Void set(_Transforms^  value);
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public: [System::Xml::Serialization::XmlElement("DigestMethod", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig")]
    property _DigestMethod^  DigestMethod {
        _DigestMethod^  get();
        System::Void set(_DigestMethod^  value);
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public: [System::Xml::Serialization::XmlElement("DigestValue", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig")]
    property System::String^ DigestValue {
        System::String^ get();
        System::Void set(System::String^ value);
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public: [System::Xml::Serialization::XmlElement("Id", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig")]
    property System::String^ Id {
        System::String^ get();
        System::Void set(System::String^ value);
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public: [System::Xml::Serialization::XmlElement("Type", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig")]
    property System::String^ Type {
        System::String^ get();
        System::Void set(System::String^ value);
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public: [System::Xml::Serialization::XmlElement("URI", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig")]
    property System::String^ URI {
        System::String^ get();
        System::Void set(System::String^ value);
    }
};


public ref class _Transforms {

    private: _Transform^  transformField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public: [System::Xml::Serialization::XmlElement("Transform", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig")]
    property _Transform^  Transform {
        _Transform^  get();
        System::Void set(_Transform^  value);
    }
};


public ref class _Transform {

    private: System::String^  algorithmField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public: [System::Xml::Serialization::XmlElement("Algorithm", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig")]
    property System::String^  Algorithm {
        System::String^  get();
        System::Void set(System::String^  value);
    }
};

[System::Xml::Serialization::XmlRoot("DigestMethod", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig")]
public ref class _DigestMethod {

private: System::String ^algorithmField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public: [System::Xml::Serialization::XmlElement("Algorithm", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig")]
    property System::String^  Algorithm {
        System::String^  get();
        System::Void set(System::String^  value);
    }
};



public ref class _SignedInfo {

    private: _CanonicalizationMethod^  canonicalizationMethodField;

    private: _SignatureMethod^  signatureMethodField;

    private: _Reference^  referenceField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public: [System::Xml::Serialization::XmlElement("CanonicalizationMethod", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig")]
    property _CanonicalizationMethod^  CanonicalizationMethod {
        _CanonicalizationMethod^  get();
        System::Void set(_CanonicalizationMethod^  value);
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public: [System::Xml::Serialization::XmlElement("SignatureMethod", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig")]
    property _SignatureMethod^  SignatureMethod {
        _SignatureMethod^  get();
        System::Void set(_SignatureMethod^  value);
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public: [System::Xml::Serialization::XmlElement("Reference", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig")]
    property _Reference^  Reference {
        _Reference^  get();
        System::Void set(_Reference^  value);
    }
};


public ref class _CanonicalizationMethod {

    private: System::String^  algorithmField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public: [System::Xml::Serialization::XmlElement("Algorithm", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig")]
    property System::String^  Algorithm {
        System::String^  get();
        System::Void set(System::String^  value);
    }
};


public ref class _SignatureMethod {

    private: System::String ^algorithmField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public: [System::Xml::Serialization::XmlElement("Algorithm", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig")]
    property System::String^  Algorithm {
        System::String^  get();
        System::Void set(System::String^  value);
    }
};



public ref class signature {

    private: _SignedInfo^  signedInfoField;

    private: System::String^  signatureValueField;

    private: _KeyInfo^  keyInfoField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public: [System::Xml::Serialization::XmlElement("SignedInfo", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig")]
    property _SignedInfo^  SignedInfo {
        _SignedInfo^  get();
        System::Void set(_SignedInfo^  value);
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public: [System::Xml::Serialization::XmlElement("SignatureValue", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig")]
    property System::String^  SignatureValue {
        System::String^  get();
        System::Void set(System::String^  value);
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public: [System::Xml::Serialization::XmlElement("KeyInfo", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig")]
    property _KeyInfo^  KeyInfo {
        _KeyInfo^  get();
        System::Void set(_KeyInfo^  value);
    }
};




inline _KeyValue^  _KeyInfo::KeyValue::get() {
    return this->keyValueField;
}
inline System::Void _KeyInfo::KeyValue::set(_KeyValue^  value) {
    this->keyValueField = value;
}

inline _X509Data^  _KeyInfo::X509Data::get() {
    return this->x509DataField;
}
inline System::Void _KeyInfo::X509Data::set(_X509Data^  value) {
    this->x509DataField = value;
}


inline _RSAKeyValue^  _KeyValue::RSAKeyValue::get() {
    return this->rSAKeyValueField;
}
inline System::Void _KeyValue::RSAKeyValue::set(_RSAKeyValue^  value) {
    this->rSAKeyValueField = value;
}


inline System::String^  _RSAKeyValue::Modulus::get() {
    return this->modulusField;
}
inline System::Void _RSAKeyValue::Modulus::set(System::String^  value) {
    this->modulusField = value;
}

inline System::String^ _RSAKeyValue::Exponent::get() {
    return this->exponentField;
}
inline System::Void _RSAKeyValue::Exponent::set(System::String^ value) {
    this->exponentField = value;
}


inline System::String^  _X509Data::X509Certificate::get() {
    return this->x509CertificateField;
}
inline System::Void _X509Data::X509Certificate::set(System::String^  value) {
    this->x509CertificateField = value;
}


inline _Transforms^  _Reference::Transforms::get() {
    return this->transformsField;
}
inline System::Void _Reference::Transforms::set(_Transforms^  value) {
    this->transformsField = value;
}

inline _DigestMethod^  _Reference::DigestMethod::get() {
    return this->digestMethodField;
}
inline System::Void _Reference::DigestMethod::set(_DigestMethod^  value) {
    this->digestMethodField = value;
}

inline System::String^ _Reference::DigestValue::get() {
    return this->digestValueField;
}
inline System::Void _Reference::DigestValue::set(System::String^ value) {
    this->digestValueField = value;
}

inline System::String^ _Reference::Id::get() {
    return this->idField;
}
inline System::Void _Reference::Id::set(System::String^ value) {
    this->idField = value;
}

inline System::String^ _Reference::Type::get() {
    return this->typeField;
}
inline System::Void _Reference::Type::set(System::String^ value) {
    this->typeField = value;
}

inline System::String^ _Reference::URI::get() {
    return this->uRIField;
}
inline System::Void _Reference::URI::set(System::String^ value) {
    this->uRIField = value;
}


inline _Transform^  _Transforms::Transform::get() {
    return this->transformField;
}
inline System::Void _Transforms::Transform::set(_Transform^  value) {
    this->transformField = value;
}


inline System::String^  _Transform::Algorithm::get() {
    return this->algorithmField;
}
inline System::Void _Transform::Algorithm::set(System::String^  value) {
    this->algorithmField = value;
}


inline System::String^ _DigestMethod::Algorithm::get() {
    return this->algorithmField;
}
inline System::Void _DigestMethod::Algorithm::set(System::String^ value) {
    this->algorithmField = value;
}


inline _SignedInfo^  signature::SignedInfo::get() {
    return this->signedInfoField;
}
inline System::Void signature::SignedInfo::set(_SignedInfo^  value) {
    this->signedInfoField = value;
}

inline System::String^  signature::SignatureValue::get() {
    return this->signatureValueField;
}
inline System::Void signature::SignatureValue::set(System::String^  value) {
    this->signatureValueField = value;
}

inline _KeyInfo^  signature::KeyInfo::get() {
    return this->keyInfoField;
}
inline System::Void signature::KeyInfo::set(_KeyInfo^  value) {
    this->keyInfoField = value;
}


inline _CanonicalizationMethod^  _SignedInfo::CanonicalizationMethod::get() {
    return this->canonicalizationMethodField;
}
inline System::Void _SignedInfo::CanonicalizationMethod::set(_CanonicalizationMethod^  value) {
    this->canonicalizationMethodField = value;
}

inline _SignatureMethod^  _SignedInfo::SignatureMethod::get() {
    return this->signatureMethodField;
}
inline System::Void _SignedInfo::SignatureMethod::set(_SignatureMethod^  value) {
    this->signatureMethodField = value;
}

inline _Reference^  _SignedInfo::Reference::get() {
    return this->referenceField;
}
inline System::Void _SignedInfo::Reference::set(_Reference^  value) {
    this->referenceField = value;
}


inline System::String^  _CanonicalizationMethod::Algorithm::get() {
    return this->algorithmField;
}
inline System::Void _CanonicalizationMethod::Algorithm::set(System::String^  value) {
    this->algorithmField = value;
}


inline System::String^ _SignatureMethod::Algorithm::get() {
    return this->algorithmField;
}
inline System::Void _SignatureMethod::Algorithm::set(System::String^ value) {
    this->algorithmField = value;
}
};

///====================================================================================

public ref class AA{
public:
    System::String^ version;
};

public ref class CC{
public:
    System::String^ Id;

    public: [System::Xml::Serialization::XmlElement("Signature", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig")]
    ds::signature^  Signature 
};

public ref class BB{
public:
    CC ^cc
};

[System::Xml::Serialization::XmlRoot("test", Namespace = "")]
public ref class test {
public:
    AA ^aa;
    BB ^bb;

};

//==============================================================================

           NameTable^ nt = gcnew NameTable();
           XmlNamespaceManager ^ namesp = gcnew XmlNamespaceManager (nt);

           namesp->AddNamespace("ds", "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#");
           XmlSerializer^ serializer = gcnew XmlSerializer( test::typeid, "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#");

           // A FileStream is needed to read the XML document.
           FileStream^ fs = gcnew FileStream( filename,FileMode::Open );

           XmlReader^ reader = gcnew XmlTextReader( fs,namesp->NameTable);

           // Declare an object variable of the type to be deserialized.
           test^ i;

           // Use the Deserialize method to restore the object's state.
           i = dynamic_cast<test^>(serializer->Deserialize( reader));
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a few problems here:

1. The namespace in the XML is [`http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmldsig-core2/) but in your c++ attribute decorations you omit the trailing `#`, for instance:

   ```
   public: [System::Xml::Serialization::XmlElement("Signature", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig")]
   ds::signature^  Signature
   ```

   The namespace mismatch causes the signature not to be read.
2. Several of the fields that you have decorated with `XmlElement` actually appear as attributes in the XML file, and thus need to be decorated with `XmlAttribute`, for instance:

   ```
   public: [System::Xml::Serialization::XmlElement("Id", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig")]
   property System::String^ Id {
       System::String^ get();
       System::Void set(System::String^ value);
   }
   ```
3. In addition, all the fields that need to be marked as attributes also need to be placed in the empty namespace.  For instance, in the line `<ds:Reference Id="1" Type="" URI="something">`, notice that `Id`, `Type` and `URI` do *not* have a `ds:` prefix?  That means they're not in any namespace.

With these issues fixed in the code below, I can read the XML you provide.

```
public ref class _KeyInfo {

    private: _KeyValue^  keyValueField;

    private: _X509Data^  x509DataField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public: [System::Xml::Serialization::XmlElement("KeyValue", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#")]
    property _KeyValue^  KeyValue {
        _KeyValue^  get();
        System::Void set(_KeyValue^  value);
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public: [System::Xml::Serialization::XmlElement("X509Data", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#")]
    property _X509Data^  X509Data {
        _X509Data^  get();
        System::Void set(_X509Data^  value);
    }
};


public ref class _KeyValue {

    private: _RSAKeyValue^  rSAKeyValueField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public: [System::Xml::Serialization::XmlElement("RSAKeyValue", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#")]
    property _RSAKeyValue^  RSAKeyValue {
        _RSAKeyValue^  get();
        System::Void set(_RSAKeyValue^  value);
    }
};


public ref class _RSAKeyValue {

    private: System::String^  modulusField;

    private: System::String^ exponentField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public: [System::Xml::Serialization::XmlElement("Modulus", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#")]
    property System::String^  Modulus {
        System::String^  get();
        System::Void set(System::String^  value);
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public: [System::Xml::Serialization::XmlElement("Exponent", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#")]
    property System::String^ Exponent {
        System::String^ get();
        System::Void set(System::String^ value);
    }
};


public ref class _X509Data {

    private: System::String^  x509CertificateField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public: [System::Xml::Serialization::XmlElement("X509Certificate", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#")]
    property System::String^  X509Certificate {
        System::String^  get();
        System::Void set(System::String^  value);
    }
};


public ref class _Reference {

    private: _Transforms^  transformsField;

    private: _DigestMethod^  digestMethodField;

    private: System::String^ digestValueField;

    private: System::String^ idField;

    private: System::String^ typeField;

    private: System::String^ uRIField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public: [System::Xml::Serialization::XmlElement("Transforms", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#")]
    property _Transforms^  Transforms {
        _Transforms^  get();
        System::Void set(_Transforms^  value);
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public: [System::Xml::Serialization::XmlElement("DigestMethod", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#")]
    property _DigestMethod^  DigestMethod {
        _DigestMethod^  get();
        System::Void set(_DigestMethod^  value);
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public: [System::Xml::Serialization::XmlElement("DigestValue", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#")]
    property System::String^ DigestValue {
        System::String^ get();
        System::Void set(System::String^ value);
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public: [System::Xml::Serialization::XmlAttribute("Id", Namespace = "")]
    property System::String^ Id {
        System::String^ get();
        System::Void set(System::String^ value);
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public: [System::Xml::Serialization::XmlAttribute("Type", Namespace = "")]
    property System::String^ Type {
        System::String^ get();
        System::Void set(System::String^ value);
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public: [System::Xml::Serialization::XmlAttribute("URI", Namespace = "")]
    property System::String^ URI {
        System::String^ get();
        System::Void set(System::String^ value);
    }
};


public ref class _Transforms {

    private: _Transform^  transformField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public: [System::Xml::Serialization::XmlElement("Transform", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#")]
    property _Transform^  Transform {
        _Transform^  get();
        System::Void set(_Transform^  value);
    }
};


public ref class _Transform {

    private: System::String^  algorithmField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public: [System::Xml::Serialization::XmlAttribute("Algorithm", Namespace = "")]
    property System::String^  Algorithm {
        System::String^  get();
        System::Void set(System::String^  value);
    }
};

[System::Xml::Serialization::XmlRoot("DigestMethod", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#")]
public ref class _DigestMethod {

private: System::String ^algorithmField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public: [System::Xml::Serialization::XmlAttribute("Algorithm", Namespace = "")]
    property System::String^  Algorithm {
        System::String^  get();
        System::Void set(System::String^  value);
    }
};



public ref class _SignedInfo {

    private: _CanonicalizationMethod^  canonicalizationMethodField;

    private: _SignatureMethod^  signatureMethodField;

    private: _Reference^  referenceField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public: [System::Xml::Serialization::XmlElement("CanonicalizationMethod", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#")]
    property _CanonicalizationMethod^  CanonicalizationMethod {
        _CanonicalizationMethod^  get();
        System::Void set(_CanonicalizationMethod^  value);
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public: [System::Xml::Serialization::XmlElement("SignatureMethod", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#")]
    property _SignatureMethod^  SignatureMethod {
        _SignatureMethod^  get();
        System::Void set(_SignatureMethod^  value);
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public: [System::Xml::Serialization::XmlElement("Reference", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#")]
    property _Reference^  Reference {
        _Reference^  get();
        System::Void set(_Reference^  value);
    }
};


public ref class _CanonicalizationMethod {

    private: System::String^  algorithmField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public: [System::Xml::Serialization::XmlAttribute("Algorithm", Namespace = "")]
    property System::String^  Algorithm {
        System::String^  get();
        System::Void set(System::String^  value);
    }
};


public ref class _SignatureMethod {

    private: System::String ^algorithmField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public: [System::Xml::Serialization::XmlAttribute("Algorithm", Namespace = "")]
    property System::String^  Algorithm {
        System::String^  get();
        System::Void set(System::String^  value);
    }
};



public ref class signature {

    private: _SignedInfo^  signedInfoField;

    private: System::String^  signatureValueField;

    private: _KeyInfo^  keyInfoField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public: [System::Xml::Serialization::XmlElement("SignedInfo", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#")]
    property _SignedInfo^  SignedInfo {
        _SignedInfo^  get();
        System::Void set(_SignedInfo^  value);
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public: [System::Xml::Serialization::XmlElement("SignatureValue", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#")]
    property System::String^  SignatureValue {
        System::String^  get();
        System::Void set(System::String^  value);
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public: [System::Xml::Serialization::XmlElement("KeyInfo", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#")]
    property _KeyInfo^  KeyInfo {
        _KeyInfo^  get();
        System::Void set(_KeyInfo^  value);
    }
};




inline _KeyValue^  _KeyInfo::KeyValue::get() {
    return this->keyValueField;
}
inline System::Void _KeyInfo::KeyValue::set(_KeyValue^  value) {
    this->keyValueField = value;
}

inline _X509Data^  _KeyInfo::X509Data::get() {
    return this->x509DataField;
}
inline System::Void _KeyInfo::X509Data::set(_X509Data^  value) {
    this->x509DataField = value;
}


inline _RSAKeyValue^  _KeyValue::RSAKeyValue::get() {
    return this->rSAKeyValueField;
}
inline System::Void _KeyValue::RSAKeyValue::set(_RSAKeyValue^  value) {
    this->rSAKeyValueField = value;
}


inline System::String^  _RSAKeyValue::Modulus::get() {
    return this->modulusField;
}
inline System::Void _RSAKeyValue::Modulus::set(System::String^  value) {
    this->modulusField = value;
}

inline System::String^ _RSAKeyValue::Exponent::get() {
    return this->exponentField;
}
inline System::Void _RSAKeyValue::Exponent::set(System::String^ value) {
    this->exponentField = value;
}


inline System::String^  _X509Data::X509Certificate::get() {
    return this->x509CertificateField;
}
inline System::Void _X509Data::X509Certificate::set(System::String^  value) {
    this->x509CertificateField = value;
}


inline _Transforms^  _Reference::Transforms::get() {
    return this->transformsField;
}
inline System::Void _Reference::Transforms::set(_Transforms^  value) {
    this->transformsField = value;
}

inline _DigestMethod^  _Reference::DigestMethod::get() {
    return this->digestMethodField;
}
inline System::Void _Reference::DigestMethod::set(_DigestMethod^  value) {
    this->digestMethodField = value;
}

inline System::String^ _Reference::DigestValue::get() {
    return this->digestValueField;
}
inline System::Void _Reference::DigestValue::set(System::String^ value) {
    this->digestValueField = value;
}

inline System::String^ _Reference::Id::get() {
    return this->idField;
}
inline System::Void _Reference::Id::set(System::String^ value) {
    this->idField = value;
}

inline System::String^ _Reference::Type::get() {
    return this->typeField;
}
inline System::Void _Reference::Type::set(System::String^ value) {
    this->typeField = value;
}

inline System::String^ _Reference::URI::get() {
    return this->uRIField;
}
inline System::Void _Reference::URI::set(System::String^ value) {
    this->uRIField = value;
}


inline _Transform^  _Transforms::Transform::get() {
    return this->transformField;
}
inline System::Void _Transforms::Transform::set(_Transform^  value) {
    this->transformField = value;
}


inline System::String^  _Transform::Algorithm::get() {
    return this->algorithmField;
}
inline System::Void _Transform::Algorithm::set(System::String^  value) {
    this->algorithmField = value;
}


inline System::String^ _DigestMethod::Algorithm::get() {
    return this->algorithmField;
}
inline System::Void _DigestMethod::Algorithm::set(System::String^ value) {
    this->algorithmField = value;
}


inline _SignedInfo^  signature::SignedInfo::get() {
    return this->signedInfoField;
}
inline System::Void signature::SignedInfo::set(_SignedInfo^  value) {
    this->signedInfoField = value;
}

inline System::String^  signature::SignatureValue::get() {
    return this->signatureValueField;
}
inline System::Void signature::SignatureValue::set(System::String^  value) {
    this->signatureValueField = value;
}

inline _KeyInfo^  signature::KeyInfo::get() {
    return this->keyInfoField;
}
inline System::Void signature::KeyInfo::set(_KeyInfo^  value) {
    this->keyInfoField = value;
}


inline _CanonicalizationMethod^  _SignedInfo::CanonicalizationMethod::get() {
    return this->canonicalizationMethodField;
}
inline System::Void _SignedInfo::CanonicalizationMethod::set(_CanonicalizationMethod^  value) {
    this->canonicalizationMethodField = value;
}

inline _SignatureMethod^  _SignedInfo::SignatureMethod::get() {
    return this->signatureMethodField;
}
inline System::Void _SignedInfo::SignatureMethod::set(_SignatureMethod^  value) {
    this->signatureMethodField = value;
}

inline _Reference^  _SignedInfo::Reference::get() {
    return this->referenceField;
}
inline System::Void _SignedInfo::Reference::set(_Reference^  value) {
    this->referenceField = value;
}


inline System::String^  _CanonicalizationMethod::Algorithm::get() {
    return this->algorithmField;
}
inline System::Void _CanonicalizationMethod::Algorithm::set(System::String^  value) {
    this->algorithmField = value;
}


inline System::String^ _SignatureMethod::Algorithm::get() {
    return this->algorithmField;
}
inline System::Void _SignatureMethod::Algorithm::set(System::String^ value) {
    this->algorithmField = value;
}
};

///====================================================================================

public ref class AA{
public:
    System::String^ version;
};

public ref class CC{
public:
    System::String^ Id;

    public: [System::Xml::Serialization::XmlElement("Signature", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#")]
    ds::signature^  Signature; 
};

public ref class BB{
public:
    CC ^cc;
};

[System::Xml::Serialization::XmlRoot("test", Namespace = "")]
public ref class test {
public:
    AA ^aa;
    BB ^bb;

};
```

For the future, one way to check your work would have been to use [`xsd.exe` to generate c# classes for your XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), then compare the auto-generated c# classes with your manually created c++ classes.  You would probably have seen the problem.